# Hiding scratches in engineered hardwood floors

Tags: hardwood-floor

Similar to this question but I am not trying to repair, only hide, scratches:

[How can I repair scratches in engineered hardwood floors?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5380/how-can-i-repair-scratches-in-engineered-hardwood-floors)

I have some builder-grade engineered hardwood floors that have built up many scratches that do not penetrate the color but are visible when looking for them. I asked the flooring folks at one of the big box stores for advice and they said some self-leveling clear polyurethane might hide the scratches. Unfortunately this did nothing except fill in the grooves. My next attempt was going to try a colored polyurethane  of a similar shade. Has anyone been successful in trying something like this? I am trying to avoid replacing the floor as I am in the process of selling but everyone that has seen the home has mentioned the scratches.
[image]

Comment: I remember seeing ads for wax like crayons made for hiding scratches.  Not sure if they just colour or maybe wood filler crayons.  Matching the colour of the floor will be the hardest.  This will hide only and do not know how long it lasts with being walked on.  Your buyers might not be to happy with you in a few months/years.

Comment: @crip659 Unfortunately this is millions of scratches over the entire floor. They are not through the surface color. I have used the pens and crayons for deeper scratches.

Comment: With the added pictures, the first answer on the link is probably the best.  Sanding will have to done very carefully, but you may not need to go as deep as the deepest scratches.  People buying will knock off the cost of redoing those floor/s from their offer anyway.

Comment: location? in your local market "do nothing" might be a good idea

Comment: @crip659 Unfortunately this specific engineered hardwood has almost no veneer. Any sanding destroys it completely (I tested on some leftover). Other than replacing it, my last thought was multiple coats of a slightly darker poly to see if it hides and fills.

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica I am in Douglas County Colorado which is a pretty hot market but have had all showings so far bring up the floor with no offers. I have modified the price and now want to try to fix the major complaint.

Comment: These would be better described as _dents_, not scratches. That's what they are, despite their elongated shape.

Comment: I might try a filler-type floor wax.

Comment: @RohitGupta No it doesn't. If you read my question I mention that post.

Comment: I love when the question gets closed and they don't even read it.